# how to send email using asp.net3.5,c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want send Email using Asp.net3.5, c#.net. I am able to send it using smtp.gmail.com with my ID ss@gmail.com, but my client given there details to send from there Id. With that I am unable to send. Details looks different like .Ex. xxx.xxx.com not like smtp.gmail.com there is no SMTP word in that host name. Please help me, how to send Email?

Comment: Can you add your current code? So we can have a look at where it might go wrong.

Comment: code is working fine if i give my  gmail details like Host: Smtp.gmail.com band uid :ss@gmail.com pwd: xxxx.but when i changed to their details only unable to send

Comment: what error message (exception) do you receive when you try to send the mail with your clients credetials? "With that I am unable to send" doesn't give us enough information to help you. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();

message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate",1 );
message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername","SmtpHostUserName" );
message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword","SmtpHostPassword" );

message.From="from e-mail";
message.To="to e-mail";
message.Subject="Message Subject";
message.Body="Message Body";

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer="SMTP Server Address";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

For More info check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dk1fb84h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `smtp.gmail.com` use `mail.XXX.com`, you will be able to sent mail.

Comment: but my client provide me deffernt Host name..there is no SMTP or MAIl in that host name which they given to me ..just like xxxx.xxxx.com only how can i..? cann i ask them to provide SMTP address again

Comment: @santhosh, a server name doesn't have to have `smtp` or `mail` in it for it to be acting as a mail server. It could be called `potato.domain.com` and still be a mailserver =)

Comment: So..like this mail server name how to send email using Asp.net i worked with smtp.domain.com like this process only please help me iam hanged here how to send email like potato.domain.com

Comment: moreover you also have to edit for the boolean value, sequre SMTP allows or not. Google allows secure SMTP while others not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sites on the net which will give you explanation and code as to how you can send mails in asp.net 3.5. You just need to google a bit. I have listed some sites which might be helpful to you. Compare your code with the ones given on these sites and check where you have made a mistake. Also if you can post your code here then we would be in a better position to help you out.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dchoksi/SendingMail02132007002923AM/SendingMail.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=65&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030720.asp

http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2009/07/sending-email-through.html

Regards,

Samar